# When csum_partial_copy_from_user() is called during a sendfile

Tags: c, linux, sendfile

Here is something I googled:

`sendfile()` is like `write()`, only directly from descriptor to a socket. That eliminates copying the data from the buffer cache to a buffer in user space.

Current NICs can do scatter-gather `I/O`, i.e. they can take the packet header from a kernel buffer, but the packet contents from the buffer cache(csum partial copy from user).

The result is called Zero Copy TCP and it is the ultimate goal.

My question is:

What is the purpose of `csum_partial_copy_from_user()` and when it is called? I followed the process of sendfile until `dev_queue_xmit()`, but I didn't find where it is called. Thanks

Comment: Do the comments [above their declarations](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/checksum.h#L4) answer your first question? The second can be answered with a simple cross-reference: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=csum_partial_copy_from_user